# Weyl tensor decomposition

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, representation-theory

I am trying to verify the relatation between Weyl tensor and its magnetic and electric parts:

$$C_{\mu\nu\kappa\lambda}=(g_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}g_{\kappa\lambda\gamma\delta}-\epsilon_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\epsilon_{\kappa\lambda\gamma\delta})u^{\alpha}u^{\gamma}E^{\beta\delta}(u)+(\epsilon_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}g_{\kappa\lambda\gamma\delta}+g_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\epsilon_{\kappa\lambda\gamma\delta})u^{\alpha}u^{\gamma}H^{\beta\delta}(u)$$

where

$$E_{\mu\nu}(u)=u^{\kappa}u^{\lambda}C_{\mu\nu\kappa\lambda} \qquad H_{\mu\nu}(u)=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\kappa(\mu}u^{\kappa}u^{\lambda}C_{\ \ \nu)\lambda}^{\alpha\beta}.$$

and  $g_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}=g_{\mu\alpha}g_{\nu\beta}-g_{\mu\beta}g_{\nu\alpha}=-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{\mu\nu}^{\kappa\lambda}\epsilon_{\kappa\lambda\alpha\beta}=g_{[\mu\nu][\alpha\beta]}=g_{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}$

I wrote the first addend as:

$$2!(u_{\kappa}u_{[\mu}E_{\nu]\lambda}+u_{\lambda}u_{[\nu}E_{\mu]\kappa}+u_{\lambda}u_{[\mu}E_{\nu]\kappa}-E_{\kappa[\mu}g_{\lambda]\nu}+u_{\kappa}u_{[\mu}E_{\nu]\lambda}-E_{\lambda[\mu}g_{\kappa]\nu})=2!(2u_{\kappa}u_{[\mu}E_{\nu]\lambda})-E_{\kappa[\mu}g_{\lambda]\nu}-E_{\lambda[\mu}g_{\kappa]\nu}).$$

I tried to wrote also the second addend but without a simple form and the calculations seems long...
Is there any way to make calculations fast?